# Interpreting C pre pre processor code

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor, stringification

Given `#define LOG_OBJECT(object)  (NSLog(@"" #object @" %@ %@:%d”, [object description], [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__));` The statement `LOG_OBJECT(self);` will produce:

> 2014-07-18 17:43:30.041 FrogCamera[12484:2144843] self
>    ViewController.m:20

I wish to understand how the preprocessor code works. How can I see the statement that the pre processor produced?

Specifically:

1. Why the whole #define statement is wrapped in `( )` ?
2. Is `#object` a text replacement for what ever value was provided ?
3. Why the requirement for `@""` before the `#object` ?
4. Namely how is `@“” #object @“ %@ %@:%d”` is transformed to `@"self %@ %@:%d"` ?

Here’s a usage example:

```
@interface ViewController ()
#define LOG_OBJECT(object)  (NSLog(@"" #object @" %@ %@:%d", [object description], [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__));
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    LOG_OBJECT(self);
    // = 2014-07-18 17:48:19.439 FrogCamera[12597:2151087] self <ViewController: 0x79755000> ViewController.m:20
    (NSLog(@"self %@ %@:%d", [self description], [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__));
    // = 2014-07-18 17:48:19.440 FrogCamera[12597:2151087] self <ViewController: 0x79755000> ViewController.m:21
}
@end
```

See [GlobalUtilities.h](https://github.com/amattn/AMNGlobalUtilities/blob/master/GlobalUtilities.h#L49) for origin of LOG_OBJECT statement.

Comment: Based on C, 2. `#` is an operator. 4. Adjacent string literals are concatenated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather simple:

1. Parenthesis in macros are used everytime when the expanded macro could do something unexpected. A typical example is:

   ```
   #define SUM(A, B) A + B
   SUM(1, 1) * 3 //the expected result is 6, the real result is 1 + 1 * 3 = 4
   ```

   Adding parenthesis around every macro is a good programming convention to prevent this type of errors.
2. `#param` is a *stringification* operator. It wraps the parameter in quotes - e.g., parameter `value` is converted to `"value"`.
3. The stringification operator creates a C string, which is an array of characters (`char *`). The author wanted a `NSString *`, that's why he is adding an `@` in the beginning. Note that `@"aaa" "bbb"` is equivalent to `@"aaabbb"` (this feature enables us to split strings over multiple lines). However, this is not very elegant. Using a `%s` would make it a bit simpler.
4. It is converted only to `@"" "self" @" %@ %@:%d"`. The compiler considers consecutive strings as one string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see what the preprocessor macros expand to, with the file open click the **Product** menu, then **Perform Action->PreProcess "ViewController.m"**. This will let you see what the expanded source, with the macros replaced, looks like. For more details on what you can do with macros, see the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/cpp/Macros.html#Macros)